# 2D Mobile Unity Game Splash Screen taking a long time to load

Tags: android, performance, unity-game-engine

I am making a 2D Android game in Unity and all of a sudden the splash screen that comes up as the game loads when you first open it is taking a long time to load. The game used to load the splash screen as soon as you clicked the app icon but now it takes a couple seconds to appear from a black screen and then takes a couple seconds after it is done to let the game actually start. I'm not sure what is causing the game to take so long to load. The game is composed of a large 2D tile map imported from Tiled (split into a couple meshes so it does not take too long to render), a menu system that involves 6 different canvases, and some songs that load in, nothing too hard at all. Any idea what could be causing the long load time?

Comment: Is it your own Spash Screen, or the one from Unity?

Comment: @Isuka happens with either

Answer (score 0):

Displays the total duration of the splash screen sequence, in seconds. This is the total of all logos plus 0.5 seconds for fading out.

*Note: Your application’s splash screen might display for longer if the first Scene isn’t ready to play. In this case, the splash screen shows only the background image or color and then fades out when the first Scene is ready to play.*

Comment: yes as gary explained is the reason, you can fix it by showing the user a loading screen that way they won't have to think the app is stuck